# How to get the text of shape in kendo diagram after drag and drop shape?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a simple shapes, when i am clicking any of the shape it will display the text of that particular shape in alert box, like that only i have to get the text of shape after dragging any of the shape.

I have some code to display the text for shape after click event same functionality i want in drag event.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="diagram"></div>
<script>
  $("#diagram").kendoDiagram({
    shapes:[
      {
        id:"1",
        content:{
          text: "State 1"
        },
        x: 20,
        y: 20
      },
      {
        id:"2",
        content: {
          text: "State 2"
        },
        x: 160,
        y: 20
      },
      {
        id:"3",
        content: {
          text: "State 3"
        },
        x: 300,
        y: 20
      }

    ],
    connections:[
      {
        from: "1",
        to: "2"
      },
      {
      from:"2",
      to:"3"
      }
    ],
    click: onClick,
    dragEnd: onDragEnd
  });

  function onDragEnd(e){
    if(e.shapes.length > 0){
      debugger
      alert("Finished dragging " + e.shapes.content.text + " shapes");
    }
  }

  function onClick(e) {
            if (e.item instanceof kendo.dataviz.diagram.Shape) {
                alert(e.item.options.content ? e.item.options.content.text : "No content.");
            }
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever i move or drag the shape it should display the text of that particular shape. like as in click on shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dragEnd: onDragEnd`

just have  to make an small change into the function.

```
    if(e.shapes.length > 0){
      debugger
      alert("Finished dragging " + e.shapes[0].options.content.text + " shapes");
    }
  }
```

Just replace the alert box of question with this.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your connections:

```
mouseEnter: onMouseEnter
```

Then add your function:

```
function onMouseEnter(e){
         if (e.item instanceof kendo.dataviz.diagram.Shape) {
                    alert(e.item.options.content ? e.item.options.content.text : "No content.");
                }

      }
```

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/diagram/events/mouseenter